# Python: Paramiko hangs when trying to execute commands over SSH

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssh, paramiko

I'm fairly new to how Paramiko works, but my main objective is to be able to run automated commands over SSH using Python.

I have the following code and I am trying to run a simple `ls` command to start off with but for some odd reason the code seems to get stuck and no output or error messages are produced.

```
import sys
import paramiko as pm
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
import os

class AllowAllKeys(pm.MissingHostKeyPolicy):
    def missing_host_key(self, client, hostname, key):
        return

HOST = '192.168.31.1'
USER = 'admin'
PASSWORD = 'admin'

client = pm.SSHClient()
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(pm.AutoAddPolicy())

client.connect(HOST, username=USER, password=PASSWORD)

channel = client.invoke_shell()
stdin = channel.makefile('wb')
stdout = channel.makefile('rb')

stdin.write('''
ls
exit
''')
print stdout.read()

stdout.close()
stdin.close()
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Are you sure `stdin` and `stdout` are not inverted?

Comment: @mrpopo,better u can use pexpect module instead of paramiko

Comment: I wanted to use pexpect initially but I'm using a windows machine :/
Can't import resource on windows. No worries, I'll just virtualize a debian client and learn pexpect.

Answer (score 2):

I attempted the same route you were going, and didn't have much luck either.  What I then opted for were the `send()` and `recv()` methods of the paramiko Channel class.  Here is what I used:

```
>>> s = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> s.load_system_host_keys()
>>> s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>>> s.connect(HOST,USER,PASS)
>>> c = s.invoke_shell()
>>> c.send('ls')
>>> c.recv(1024)
ls
bin     etc     usr     home
proc    var     lib     tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

`import paramiko
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    target_host = 'x.x.x.x'
    target_port = 22
    target_port = 22
    pwd = ':)'
    un = 'root'
    ssh.connect( hostname = target_host , username = un, password = pwd )
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls;exit')`

Answer (score -2):

@mrpopo,try this code which uses pecpect,

```
import pexpect
import pxssh
import time
import os

    def tc(ipaddr,password):
        try:
            ss = pexpect.spawn(ipaddr)
            ss.logfile = sys.stdout
                print "SSH connecting"
                print 
        except:
            print "connection refused"
            print
            #sys.exit()

            try:
                ss.expect (':')
                ss.sendline (password +"\n")
                    print "connected"
                    time.sleep(30)
                    ss.expect (">")
                    print "connection established"
                    print

            except:
                    print "Permission denied, please try again."
                        print
                        sys.exit()
            try:
                ss.sendline ('ls\n')
                ss.expect ('>')

    tc("ssh admin@192.168.31.1,admin")
```